# Security against local attack for remote FDE decryption?

Tags: disk-encryption, tpm, luks, physical-access, ssh-host-key

**Is there any remote FDE decryption that is resistant to an attacker that has local physical access?**

Tools like [`dracut-sshd`](https://github.com/gsauthof/dracut-sshd#hardware-alternatives) need to store the private key used for the sshd server on the unencrypted boot partition, so a local attacker has the ability to become a MITM and sniff the decryption password.

*Can using a TPM to protect the sshd key foil this attack?*

Does `clevis-tang` have essentially the same problem? At the bottom of the [`tang` README.md](https://github.com/latchset/tang) is this list of security considerations:

1. Man-in-the-Middle
2. Compromise the client to gain access to `cJWK`
3. Compromise the server to gain access to `sJWK's` private key

Problem (1) is not a concern according to this document. I assume you avoid problem (3) by running the `tang` server on a FDE itself or storing the key on a HSM. Problem (2) sounds impossible to protect against if the attacker is local - is that correct?

The `tang` documentation stresses that the...

> client protect `cJWK` from prying eyes. This may include device
> permissions, filesystem permissions, security frameworks (such as
> SELinux) or even the use of hardware encryption such as a TPM

*Is the TPM option the only way to foil an attacker with physical access to the unencrypted boot partition?*

Is there any work-around that allows remote unattended FDE decryption that a local attacker cannot compromise?

Comment: Evil maid: an attacker with physical access to the device has just enough power to do any sort of evil

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ Remote attestation can protect from that.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this helpful blog](https://blog.dowhile0.org/2017/10/18/automatic-luks-volumes-unlocking-using-a-tpm2-chip/) about using TPM to auto-decrypt FDE disks, a local attacker can replace initramfs (because it resides on the unencrypted boot partition) and decrypt the disk even though the key is in TPM. I think this means *all* methods (`dracut-sshd`, `clevis/tang`, etc) suffer the same weakness.

(*Anyone care to point out which method they consider lowest risk?*)

The article claims there is no fool-proof way to accomplish what is being asked by this question -- yet. It lays out a couple ideas that people are working on for future iterations of the technology.

Comment: I believe SecureBoot is supposed to help against an attacker booting an unsecure kernel.